# Questions regarding ZTE Quartz (Surf + Talk, data transfer between internal-external storage)

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

I have some questions regarding an Android smartphone, ZTE Quartz (Z797C).

1. Can you search the internet while talking on this phone?
2. Can you transfer music, pictures, and games from the internal to the external SD card on these phones?

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much the phone, but more the network that determines if you can be on the internet while talking on the phone.

If your Data Network on your carrier uses the same network that is used for Voice, no. But if you have LTE data, for example, and GSM for voice, yes.

One reason carriers no longer mention if you can do this, like when AT&T and Verizon were going head-to-head, is because most carriers now use different networks for data than they do for voice. This means most carriers are able to do "Surf + Talk" at the same time.

To answer your other question, while typically you should only ask one question, especially if they are as unrelated as this, you can copy files from your internal storage to your external storage.